# How to set FAT32 short names in Powershell or Windows Command Shell

Tags: fat32, short-filenames

I need to write a script that sets the short name of a file on a FAT32 file system. On NTFS I can use the FSUTIL utility under windows but I cannot seem to fathom out how to do this for a FAT32 drive.

Bonus kudos for a window command or powershell script

Answer (score 0):

They made this super hard to get at, but here is one solution:
[Converting the FileSystemObject's ShortName Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee692751(v=technet.10))

Comment: Thanks, but this only returns the value, I was looking for a way to SET the value.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible because it's the limitation of the [`SetFileShortName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfileshortnamew) Win32 API which I believe `fsutil` also uses under the hood

> Sets the short name for the specified file. The file must be on an NTFS file system volume.

You can manually [hex edit the FAT32 partition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14124222/995714) to set the short names and update the checksums but it'll be quite fragile without support from the file system driver