# WINAPI SetShortName via PINVOKE returns different errors on NTFS and FAT32

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

In relation my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115519/how-to-set-fat32-short-names-in-powershell-or-windows-command-shell), I've tried to write a small program that sets a files short name given it's long name. However I'm always getting an exception thrown:

**`Error:  The parameter is incorrect` on FAT32**

**`Error:  The handle is invalid` on NTFS**

Edit: I now appreciate that I cannot call the API under FAT32

FYI: I'm running under an Administrative Console.

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    namespace Test{
      public static class Program
      {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
        public extern static IntPtr CreateFile(
             string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode,
             IntPtr SecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
             uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile
             );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool SetFileShortName(IntPtr hFile, string lpShortName);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const uint GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000;
            const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
            const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
            const uint FILE_SHARE_DELETE = 0x00000003;

            const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
            const uint BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x02000000;

            var handle = CreateFile(args[0], GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, BACKUP_SEMANTICS, IntPtr.Zero);

            bool ret = SetFileShortName(handle, args[1]);

            if (!ret)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error:  {0}", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's the same if I use FILE_SHARE DELETE or WRITE

Answer (score 2):

Based on your linked question, it sounds like you're trying to do this on a FAT32 volume. That doesn't work, from the docs for `SetShortFileName`:

> Sets the short name for the specified file. The file *must* be on an NTFS file system volume.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfileshortnamea

Emphasis mine.

Re edit:

> Error: The handle is invalid on NTFS

Is the `CreateFile` call succeeding? You seem to opening it with the appropriate permissions for `SetShortFileName` which makes me wonder if the `CreateFile` is failing and returning `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. I would check and make sure that the `CreateFile` call is succeeding.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what I need to do to get the NTFS version of the program to work.

Comment: Think I've got it - further down in the doc (RTFM!!!) SE_RESTORE_NAME is required. My code though admin is most likely missing this. Need to go to get set up first!